# Cannot build on cPanel/SSH | Laravel + Vue

Tags: vue.js, npm, cpanel

I have a cPanel server. I have ssh access to the server. Once I have pulled the new changes/files via Git, I ran `npm run build`. It gave me the following error.

[image: error screenshot]

How do I fix this error?

I checked the file/directory permissions and they were 644/755 respectively.

I searched online and could not found a solution.

I tried the following option, it still errors.

[image]

It seems there are no limits to the user too. See the below screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option in cPanel/WHM called '**Shell Fork Bomb Protection**'

I found this article about 'Shell Fork Bomb Protection': https://docs.cpanel.net/whm/security-center/shell-fork-bomb-protection/

You have disable that option in order to `npm run build`

[image]

Also to verify, when you run `ulimit -a`, you should get a higher value for `max user processes`. (compare before and after disabling 'Fork Bomb')

**Reference**

https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/cannot-build-on-cpanel-ssh-laravel-vue.711657/